# Visual Studio - deploy database - Database parameters

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, publish

At the moment, I am deploying to a server, and part of the deployment, when publishing from Visual studio, calls a script that adds a user to a group:

```
ALTER ROLE [geodeveloper] ADD MEMBER [OTWGEODI01\GEO Application Developers];
```

The server I am using is called `OTWGEODI01`

However, I create a new publish profile that points to `OTWGEODI02` - but the script above fails, as there is now member `OTWGEODI01\GEO Application Developers`

Is there a way I can have a parameter as part of the publish that changes this value in the script?

I tried to add properties to my database solution, but adding a cariable called ServerName. I set it to 'OTWGEODI02'. I then went to one of my scripts that had a direct reference to the server name:

```
ALTER ROLE [geodeveloper] ADD MEMBER [OTWGEODI01\GEO Application Developers];
```

And replaced it with:

```
ALTER ROLE [geodeveloper] ADD MEMBER [[$(ServerName)\GEO Application Developers];
```

But it tells me I have an Invalid Syntax near '\'

Can you see an error I am making? Also, every time I need to publish to different environment, I will need to go and update the database properties? Or can that somehow be based on the .publish file I am using. (I have a .publish file per database). Maybe I can end up with one publish file, and somehow select the Solution Configurations and add my environments there?

Edit:

Results in a publish error saying:

> SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 15401, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 1 Windows NT user or group '($ServerName)\GEO Application
>   Developers' not found. Check the name again.

```
CREATE USER [($ServerName)\GEO Application Developers] FOR LOGIN [($ServerName)\GEO Application Developers];
```

It didn't seem to replace the variable...

Also:

```
CREATE USER [$(ServerName)\GEO Application Developers] FOR LOGIN [$(ServerName)\GEO Application Developers];
```

Results in a built time error saying that I can't put parameters here.

Answer (score 0):

You can define variables in the Project properties (defining a new variable in the **SQLCMD Variables** tab). Then you can use this variable in your scripts (like [$(ServerName)]). 
While publishing, you can set different values depending on the server you want it to publish to.

Comment: Thanks @Amit - I just tried that but get a strange error. I have updated my  question based on your answer.

Comment: On second thoughts, you can also use the system variable `@@SERVERNAME` which will fetch you the server name. You will then need to build your sql query and execute it (dynamic query I think).